# How to put a variable like name table in a update codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In `model.php`, I have a method that I would use for more table and so I pass like parameter the name of table. My purpose is to update the row with `'code' = $code`

```
function edit_parameter($description, $code, $table){

        $param = array(
            'description' => $description
        );
        $this->db->where('code', $code);
        $this->db->update($table, $param);

    }
```

When I run this code I obtain `500 error`, but If I put in

```
$this->db->update($table, $param);
```

the name of the table, the code it works. Anyone can help me?

Comment: of course it fails if you run the code without passing the name of the table, why *wouldn't* it? you should also really develop with error reporting on rather than guessing at the problem.

Comment: $table is the name of table!

Comment: "but if i put in the name of the table the code works" ... hence your 500 error is happening when you don't put in the name of the table. if this is not the case revise your question to be clearer. update obviously requires $table be a table name that exists in your db.

Comment: I mean if I pass variable like $table the code doesn't work while if I pass $this->db->update("name_example", $param);  it works

Comment: well that is due to code outside the *scope* of the code you provided. because the relationship between $table from the functions param and `$this->db->update($table, $param);` is clear and is **not** the issue. so if i were you i'd investigate why the table param isn't getting passed to the function because that is the only valid possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other answers will likely do their job, it's not what you should want.

```
function edit_parameter($description, $code, str $table) {
    $param = array(
        'description' => $description
    );
    $this->db->where('code', $code);
    if(!$this->db->update($table, $param)) {
        return $this->db->error();
    }
}
```

This way you enforce $table being filled, so you can't even get in the function without filling $table. You shouldn't allow $table to be empty and then run a check to see if it is empty since your function will not work without it. Hence why you should force it being filled.

Comment: In my opinion, this logic shouldn't be contained in this function: if a controller method is calling this function without the $table name then that should have been handled differently in the controller by serving an error there. DB functions in models when called should have all the information they need to work. That is why we often see validation happening in controllers. Again, my opinion.

Comment: I agree but seeming the OP isn't familiar itself with repositories I didnt really bother with it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

For 500 error check u calling the correct controller's method which in turn call `edit_parameter` method

it should work unless `$table` is empty;

check `$table` first for not `empty`

```
  function edit_parameter($description,$code,$table)
  {
    if (!empty($table))
    {
       $param=array('description'=>$description);
       $this->db->where('code', $code);
       if (! $this->db->update($table,$param)) {
          return $this->db->error();
       }

    }
    else
   {
       $status = 'table not found !';
       return $status;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it's working

```
function edit_parameter($description, $code, $table = null) {
    if ($table == null || !is_string($table)) return;

    $param = array(
        'description' => $description
    );
    $this->db->where('code', $code);
    if(!$this->db->update($table, $param)) {
        return $this->db->error();
    }
}
```